# Hard drive Spins Gets detected but doesn't respond

Tags: external-hard-drive

My Hard disk is WD 500gb. 
Cutting maters short. It does spins, doesnt makes any noise, Gets detected by Disk Management, but simply doesnt work even with SATA adapter.

Is it a problem with PCB or Internal Mechanical Failure or anything else?!

[image]

Comment: You're unable to allocate it and format it by right-clicking? You can literally do nothing what so ever? Not even allocate a drive letter? If the drive is new, try to replace it with a different one. You should be able to do something with it. Unallocated simply means it isn't formatted and doesn't know where to go / what to do. Right click it and press Format or similar.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem of the sort you are describing, but it could also be something else.
You haven't specified if you have tried to initialize it or not? If it's a new or old HDD.
You hard drive currently is without any File System or partitions on it. That's why it says Unallocated. 
Do you have any information on that drive? Did this happen suddenly? If so, then something must've happened to the drive to lose it's partitions and File System. This could be from a corrupted file system to bad sectors. 
My advice would be to scan the drive with the WD Data Lifeguard Diagnostics tool, doing both Quick and Extended tests:
http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=810&lang=en

And if you did have some data on it your best chance at retrieving that data, without any further damage is to take it to a Data Recovery company. These are WD's official Data Recovery Partners:
http://support.wdc.com/recovery/index.asp?wdc_lang=en

If this is a new drive, or an old one without information on it (or at least one that matters), you should Initialize the disk by right clicking on it. Then Create a New Simple Volume by right clicking on the unallocated space (this is how you create a partition), follow the instructions, specify volume size, assign a drive letter, one that isn't use by any other device and finally format the partition (put a file system on it).

Answer (score 0):

Asssuming you are trying to format a volume on disk 1:

You usually do not format a **disk**.  Instead you create a **filesystem** inside a  **partition** on a **disk**. Your disk1 does not show any partitions. In order to use it in windows you want to right click on the disk, create a partition and then format it.

---

If all of this is abracadabra to you, compare it to a book:
You do not read a whole book (including cover art). Instead you have the physical book, an index with chapters (compare that to MBR/UEFI) and chapters.

Formatting a volume is similar to drawing nice empty lines in a chapter.

In your case you have a book but still need to write the index and format the chapter.

Answer (score -1):

I typically use a program called Partition Magic booted from it's own DVD/CD to change and test partitions on questionable drives.  There are other utilities out there if you can't get a proper partitioning of this drive.  It could have faulty sectors in particular areas of the drive.

Comment: Pretty vindictive for someone to downvote this as the utility is especially adept in this kind of situation over standard MS partitioning code.